# pythonaddin button return value

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, add-in

I have asked this question a while back but within arcgis environment without using addin. Now i am trying to do the same task to get pixel value when user click anywhere on screen, to use in later steps. Following pythonaddin button code snippet returns nothing. Any suggestions where is the catch?

```
class Val(object):
"""Implementation for Pythonaddin_addin.genW (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):
    geog = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    ras = arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(geog, "ID", "in_memory/ras", "MAXIMUM", "",30)
    pass
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The code you have written makes no sense in what little context you have provided.

Comment: I want to get a single pixel value when user click anywhere on map and use that value to create a single pixel raster.

Comment: I learned that i should use tool instead of button for interaction with screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, you must implement a [`Tool`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000027000000) add-in class instead of a button. Then, write your logic in the class's `onMouseDownMap` method. The arguments passed in to this method include the X and Y coordinates of the clicked location, in the map's coordinate system.

From there it's basically up to you to figure out what to do in response to that event, but here is a simple function to report the coordinates and cell value at the clicked location for the first raster layer in the first map in the current map document.

```py
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, None, df)
    rasterlayer = None
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.isRasterLayer:
            rasterlayer = layer
            break
    if rasterlayer:
        cellvalue = arcpy.management.GetCellValue(rasterlayer, "{} {}".format(x, y)).getOutput(0)
        pythonaddins.MessageBox("XY: {}, {}\nCell Value: {}".format(x, y, cellvalue), "Results")
```

Example output:

[image: Output]

Comment: "arcpy.management.GetCellValue" should be "arcpy.GetCellValue_management" in the above code.

Comment: Either works, try it out.